# Largest idempotent

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Given the prime power factors of $N$, is there a non-quadratic algorithm for finding the **largest** idempotent of ring $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$? (That is, the largest number $A \lt N$ such that $A^{2} \equiv A \text{mod} N$.)

I know that there are at most $8$ prime power factors ($=K$) for $N$ in the range of interest, thus at most $256 (=2^K)$ idempotents, with $0$ & $1$ being trivial.

edited: "range of interest" clause somehow got misplaced.

Comment: By "ring N," do you mean $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$?  And in this case, by "largest," do you mean largest in the range $\{0,1,\dotsc,N-1\}$?

Comment: From the context, it looks like you are just interested in the ring $\Bbb Z/(N)$?

Comment: @Paul Yes, $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.  I didn't know how to make the notation on here.  And yes, the largest integer value.

Comment: So you want sub-quadratic in terms of $N$? Maybe order the prime power factors in terms of descending magnitude and then use CRT to find a number congruent to 1 to all but the smallest and congruent to 0 to that one.

Comment: @JacobSchlather Thank you, that was a very productive suggestion.  Unfortunately, it turns out using 0 for the smallest factors doesn't guarantee the solution will be the largest idempotent.  So, it looks like I'll have to calculate all 2^n-2 non-trivial idempotents and select the largest.

Comment: There is a symmetry that might(?) be useful in some sort of approach. Since $1-e$ is an idempotent whenever $e$ is, finding very small idempotents yields very large idempotents.

Comment: @rschwieb I was aware of that, which may cut the $2^K$ numbers to test down to $2^{K-1}$.

Using the general solution of the CRT
$$\sum_i {{a}_i}{N\over n_i}\left[{N\over n_i}\right]^{-1}_{n_i}$$
calculated for each set of $a_i$ taking the values 0 and 1 will find all $2^K$ idempotents.  Is it the case that solving for $a$={0,1,1,1} and $a$={1,0,0,0} (inverting the 1's and 0's) will produce the 2 solutions that add to $N+1$?  If so, that will cut my calculation in half.

Comment: Note that the CRT problems we're asked to solve are of a special form, $x \equiv 0 \mod M$ and $x \equiv 1 \mod (N/M)$ where factors $M$ and $N/M$ are coprime.  The solution will be a multiple of $M$, so somewhat unintuitively a heuristic exists for making $M$ as large as possible.

Comment: I have reached an odd point.  After checking my code repeatedly, and 2 variations that produced the same result, I broke down and googled it.  Somehow, my solution is off by exactly 1.  The basic algorithm had to be correct, or it wouldn't have gotten that close.  I was totally at a loss as to where this extra 1 came from.

And then I realized, N=1 was being treated as a prime, for M(1)=1.  It should be M(1)=0.

Always watch your edge cases!

Comment: It looks like Project Euler 407.

Answer (score 4):

Let $N = m_1\ldots m_k$ be a prime power decomposition (distinct $m_i$ coprime).

Then $A$ is an *idempotent* modulo $N$ iff $A^2 \equiv A \mod{N}$.  Equivalently, $A$ is
an idempotent modulo each prime power factor $m_i$, which amounts to:

$$ \forall m_i \; A \equiv 0,1 \mod{m_i} $$

because $A(A-1)$ is divisible by prime power $m_i$ only if $m_i$ divides $A$ or $A-1$.
Henceforth we will refer to $0,1$ as *trivial* idempotents.  For *nontrivial*
idempotents $A$ we multiply those factors $m_i$ which divide $A$ to get the product $M$.
Then $M$ and $N/M$ are coprime and:

$$ A \equiv 0 \mod{M} $$

$$ A \equiv 1 \mod{N/M} $$

The first of these relations implies that $A = aM$. Require a reduced residue
$1 \lt A \lt N$, and it follows $0 \lt a \lt N/M$.  The coprimality of $M$ and $N/M$
gives $a \equiv M^{-1} \mod{N/M}$, thereby satisfying the second relation.

Moreover as @rschwieb pointed out, the nontrivial idempotents occur in pairs $A,A'$ s.t.
$A + A' = N + 1$ by swapping the roles of $M$ and $N/M$.  Searching for large idempotents
(but less than $N$) thus amounts to searching for small ones (but greater than $1$).

All nontrivial idempotents may be formed as distinct sums of "basic" idempotents $A_i$,
$1 \le i \le k$, taking the product $M_i$ of the $k-1$ prime powers *other* than $m_i$,
so $N/M = m_i$.  Then $A_i = a_i M_i$ where $a_i \equiv M_i^{-1} \mod{m_i}$.  One way to
solve for $a_i$ uses the [extended Euclidean 
algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to provide:

$$ a_i M_i + b_i m_i = 1 $$

Alternatively one can apply [Euler's generalization of Fermat's Little 
Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem):

$$ a_i \equiv M_i^{\phi(m_i)-1} \mod{m_i} $$

However one computes those $k$ basic solutions $a_i M_i$, all nontrivial idempotents $\mod{N}$
can be expressed as sums over proper (nonempty) subsets of them.  By this accounting there
are $2^k - 2$ of them (excludes the two trivial idempotents).

---

**Example:** Let $N = 10^n = 2^n 5^n$.  For each $n$ there are two nontrivial idempotents,
adding up to $N + 1$. Their respective decimal representations "stabilize" by truncation
so we may summarize both parallel expansions:

$$ a_n 5^n:\; \ldots 19977392256259918212890625 $$
$$ b_n 2^n:\; \ldots 80022607743740081787109376 $$

allowing us to tell by inspection for given $n$ which of the two is larger.  I don't see
any regular pattern in these results, although the frequency of double digits looks
somewhat improbable.

Cases of this turn up in [online puzzles](http://www.qbyte.org/puzzles/p094h.html) and [older
literature](http://books.google.com/books?id=dAkAAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA28&lpg=RA1-PA28&dq=12890625).

Readers interested in extending this example may find it useful that squaring an initial
segment of the $a_n 5^n$ adds at least one extra correct digit.  The analogous fact about
the $b_n 2^n$ series requires taking a fifth power, so it's more easily derived by
"complementing" the $a_n 5^n$ series.

---

The irregularity with which the above two series of idempotents swap top position
doesn't suggest a shortcut for more general $N$ and higher number of factors $k$.

While an exhaustive search is satisfactory for small $k$, for large $k$ we should perhaps
look to the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) for
inspiration.

The set of basic solutions $\{A_1,\ldots,A_k\}$ can without loss of generality be assumed
to be ordered.  So as a first approximation to finding the largest nontrivial idempotent,
we can compare $A_k$ and $N+1-A_1$.  No single basic solution (or sum of $k-1$ of them)
could improve on that, so let's label that $E_1$.

Using two or basic solutions for an improvement would then amount to a sequence of [approximate
subset sum problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm)
targeting intervals $((j-1)N+E_j,jN-1]$ for $j=1$ up to $\frac{k}{2}$, taking $E_{j+1}$ to be the improvement if one is found, or $E_j$ otherwise.

While this seems promising as far as polynomial-time in $k$, it's only a sketch of an idea
at this point.

Comment: Thanks.  In the end, trying to program your suggested optimization would take me longer to program than the "check $2^k - 2$ possibilities" already runs (about 1 hour).  Fortunately, $k<9$ for my problem, so it's not so bad.

Comment: @JerryB: Thanks for taking the time to move the Question here from StackOverflow.  With many hard problems a theoretical improvement in complexity only has a practical benefit at very large scales, even discounting the months of additional development.  However I suspect running time of exhaustive search should only be taking less than a minute for k=8.  Would you care to post a value of N that illustrates the Question?

Comment: Well, the 1 hour runtime is actually for **all** $N$ values 1 thru $10^7$.  The maximum k=8 is for the integer with the largest number of prime power factors in that range.