# Find the four digit number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

A natural number $a$ has four digits such that $a^2$ ends with the exactly same four digits as that of $a$. Find the value of $a$?

The question was asked in a subjective maths olympiad and is certainly not missing any detail. The answer is 9376 as the square of 9376=87909376 but i am not able to understand how to solve it.
I got it thanks ajotatxe

Comment: _HINT_: try first with one digit and work your way from there.

Comment: It might be worth reading *How to ask a good question?* (linked in the on hold banner). In particular, [the part about context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) might be relevant here.

Comment: Why do you think this question is off topic?

Comment: This question has been put on hold because you need to give "your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it". However, that can be pretty tough when you don't even know where to start. ajotatxe has given you some good info. Here are a few more hints. The GCD of two consecutive numbers must be 1 (can you see why?), so what does that tell us about the prime factors of $a$ and $a-1$? [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) will be useful in finding solutions for $a$.

Comment: FWIW, the general version of this problem is discussed at [Largest idempotent](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272427/largest-idempotent) but a simpler method can be used here because $10^n$ has only two distinct prime factors.

Comment: Hmm i got it the a must be divisible by 2^4 i.e. 1 6 and also a-1 must be divisible by 5^4 i.e. 625.That paves way to reach the answer 9376.

Comment: Can you guys remove it from on hold as i have got my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You must solve
$$a^2-a=a(a-1)\equiv0\pmod{10,000}$$

Note that $a$ or $a-1$ must be multiple of $5^4=625$.

Comment: Thanks i got it a must be divisible by 16 and a-1 by 625